# "Sign as Different User" option does not appear in WelcomeMenuBox

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-masterpage, user, editing-menu

I created new custom masterpage. But "Sign as different user" option disappear in WelcomeMenuBox.

is there a way to add this option, maybe i remove it by accidently?

[image]

Comment: Is this Sharepoint 2013 on premise? There is no option for "Sign in as a different user" in Sp2013. So no, you haven't removed it by accident.

Comment: yes @user19952. I didn't know this but I learned. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default in SharePoint 2013 there is no option for "Sign in as different user".
Follow the below steps to enable it

Step: 1

Go to the location C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web ServerExtensions\15\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES.

Here we have a file named welcome.ascx.

Step 2:
Open that file and add the blow code

```
<SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" ID="ID_LoginAsDifferentUser"
  Text="<%$Resources:wss,personalactions_loginasdifferentuser%>"
  Description="<%$Resources:wss,personalactions_loginasdifferentuserdescription%>"
  MenuGroupId="100"
  Sequence="100"
  UseShortId="true"
  />
```

Paste this code above the tag which has ID_RequestAcess.

Step 3:
Refresh the site it will be available.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Anuja. I followed this steps and my issue is solved.

Comment: Good to know, Please mark it as answer if this useful to you